# Can anyone identify this bike with its frame?

Tags: frames, identify-this-bike

Can anyone help me identify this bike? This bike has a serial number JS10092683.
I doubt it's a Giant because I think it's just a sticker.

[image: A red MTB with black accents. Most notable, the tube in line with the seat post shows a gap (for the suspension), with the tube completing the triangle bent forward in a sharp angle.]
*Click on the image for a larger version*

Comment: If we are to have any hope of identifying this bike, we need a better photo. It has to show the whole frame. Even then identification can be tricky, but the info provided is not helpful. As to the serial #, they are useless to the general public and you might as well call Giant, if you can, and ask them.

Comment: Why do you think it's not a Giant?

Comment: It may be possible to look at the logo over the years and figure out when it changes, to help indicate a year range ?

Comment: Guessing mid to late 1990's.  The single pivot suspension makes it very early of very BSO.  Shocks with no rubber boot make is post 1995ish.  Could just as easily be a BSO with Giant stickers.

Comment: It looks to me as though someone sanded off the top of the top and down tubes, respectively , with an angle grinder.

Comment: @DanielRHicks aren't all Giant serial number GM-_something_? Trek used JS at some point, but I doubt this is one.

Answer (score 2):

I found a similar bike frame geometry with my bike. Its called a "Schwinn Ditch 2.0" and looks like from [bikeindex.org: Schwinn Ditch 2.0](https://bikeindex.org/bikes/493322) [image]

Comment: Close, but the bottom bracket (BB) on yours is part of the rear triangle assembly where this one has the BB on the main frame. Actually having the BB on the rear triangle is fairly unusual and could indicate that the bike is a Giant vs a BSO. The theory is that pedalling forces don’t influence the suspension with that setup.

Answer (score 0):

STARTER:    It is **not** a Giant VT, but has some vague similarities in the not-straight seat tube.   This is a 2003, yours looks older.

The "direct-line" design of how the shock is placed, is also very old.  I'd estimate 2000 at latest and probably earlier.

[image: From https://coresites-cdn-adm.imgix.net/bikemagic_new/wp-content/uploads/2003/09/vt_side_big.jpg]

---

It is also NOT a Giant ATR-DSX 2 although the line that the suspension follows is closer.   By this I mean that there is no pivot bar to rotate the direction of suspension movement, allowing for a harder shock giving more overall travel.

[image: From https://www.carousell.sg/p/giant-old-school-full-suspension-mountain-bike-1083547106/]

---

It is impossible to prove a negative, but I have strong doubts this was a Giant frame.

Your best option might be to contact Giant customer support with the serial number and ask directly.   If you get a useful answer, please do come back and add a new reply to this question, for closure and future-readers.

Comment: After some searching I found a similar design with my frame, the Schwinn 2.0.

Comment: @Leonidas2 NICE find!   Please add an answer with that info (SE totally permits self answering)   With that name, I found that its called a "Schwinn Ditch 2.0" and looks like https://files.bikeindex.org/uploads/Pu/142959/large_20181213_154611.jpg   from https://bikeindex.org/bikes/493322

Comment: The Schwinn is vaguely similar, but the frame in question looks much cheaper and many details are different.

Comment: @VladimirFГероямслава true - its the most-similar so-far, and is the best lead so-far.